# Javascript: Unexpected token )

Tags: javascript, token

I've got the following script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){


    calendar = $('.fullcalendar').fullCalendar({
  defaultView: $.cookie('fullcalendar_defaultView') || 'agendaWeek',
  viewDisplay: function(view) {
    $.cookie('fullcalendar_defaultView', view.name);
    if (calendar) {
        MySetDate();
    }
  }
}

    function MySetDate() {
  var thedate = $('.fullcalendar').fullCalendar('getDate');
  raw_date = thedate + 'stringed';
  raw_split_date = raw_date.split(' ');

  switch (raw_split_date[1]) 
  {
      case 'Jan': raw_month = 0; break;
      case 'Feb': raw_month = 1; break;
      case 'Mrt': raw_month = 2; break;
      case 'Apr': raw_month = 3; break;
      case 'May': raw_month = 4; break;
      case 'Jun': raw_month = 5; break;
      case 'Jul': raw_month = 6; break;
      case 'Aug': raw_month = 7; break;
      case 'Sep': raw_month = 8; break;
      case 'Oct': raw_month = 9; break;
      case 'Nov': raw_month =10; break;
      case 'Dec': raw_month =11; break;
  }

  $.cookie('lof_y', raw_split_date[3], { expires: 2 } );
  $.cookie('lof_m', raw_month,         { expires: 2 } );
  $.cookie('lof_d', raw_split_date[2], { expires: 2 } );
  }

    function setMyView() {
    $('.fullcalendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', $.cookie('lof_y'), $.cookie('lof_m'), $.cookie('lof_d') );
    $.cookie('lof_y', null);
}


    if ($.cookie('lof_y')) {
        setMyView();
    }                  

});
```

And I get the following error on line 18 ( at function MySetDate() ):

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
```

I see the '(' at line 4 is not closed anywhere, I've tried numerous ways but none of them solved the problem (or resulted in more problems)

Can anyone assist me on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Missing `)` After calendar options :

```
calendar = $('.fullcalendar').fullCalendar({
    defaultView: $.cookie('fullcalendar_defaultView') || 'agendaWeek',
    viewDisplay: function(view) {
        $.cookie('fullcalendar_defaultView', view.name);
        if (calendar) {
            MySetDate();
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: thanks, I've tried that already, it results in: "Uncaught ReferenceError: calendar is not defined", on line 12

Comment: @Maarten: What is line 12? `if (calendar)`?

Comment: @Maarten: What? My previous suggestion? I removed it since I wasn't sure but here it is again for completeness: *"Try `var calendar` to make the variable local, or make it explicitly global with `window.calendar` if it has to be."*

Comment: just in general: when you're not acquainted with (js)-errors, it can feel like *$&*(#@&$. However, there's reason and logic to the errors produced. For one.. Syntax errors are always produced for other errors like the "Uncaught ReferenceError" .. So you know you're making progress ;)